# How do you stop the camera when application is stopped in java openCV?

Tags: java, opencv, camera, exit

When I close the vision project and then close it again the camera is still running. Is there a method to close it automatically when the program is closed?

Comment: Don't post the answer inside the question. Also, don't write "SOLVED" in the title. Instead, post a new answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In any Java class you can override finalize() and place cam.release() there. It's not guaranteed to run right away, but eventually.

Comment: I just got it working but thx! I used :public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}

Comment: Ah, you didn't say you were using a JFrame :)